# Android - Updating TextView String through AIDL Service

Tags: android, resources, service, aidl

I have an app that uses a TabHost.
Several of the Tabs share a common HUD.
I am using a service to periodically update those values by calling an AIDL function when ready.

However, since several of the Tabs are using the same HUD I would like to abstract that part out.

I thought about having the HUD.xml use a String resource as it's value and then the abstracted class can update the String resource. However, apparently Android can not update String resources programatically.

The only alternative solution I see would be using SharedPreference.
I have concerns accessing a Database everytime the value is refreshed.

Can anyone please share some options with me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, apparently Android can not update String resources programatically.

Correct.

> The only alternative solution I see
>   would be using SharedPreference. I
>   have concerns accessing a Database
>   everytime the value is refreshed.

Shared preferences are not stored in a database. They are stored in an XML file.

> Can anyone please share some options with me.

Have the service broadcast an `Intent` when it changes the data. Or, have the service call listener objects supplied by the tabs. There's probably a half-dozen other options as well, but those two should get you started down the path.